# preventing rails validation based on previous validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model with 2 validations on the 'name' attribute. It goes something like this:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => true

validate do
  errors.add(:name, "is dumb") if name_is_dumb?
end
```

I don't want the 2nd validation to run if the first validation fails (the name is not unique).

What's the best and cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Maybe check the 'errors' content

Comment: Yea, that one crossed my mind. It didn't seem like the best rails-y way, ya know?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> Callbacks are generally run in the
>   order they are defined, with the
>   exception of callbacks defined as
>   methods on the model, which are called
>   last.

So the following snippet should work:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => true

validate do
  errors.add(:name, "is dumb") unless errors[:name].nil?
end
```